# Expanding The Universe

Tags: java

My question is I'm supposed to research the size of each CelestialObject and its distance from the sun (for planets) and the distance of the moons from the planets

and

Calculate the distance between any two CelestialObject (e.g. between 2 planets and or between two moons).

I have 2 classes setup to do these calculations. My question is how do I call these to do for example, to calculate the distance between the sun, and the 2 different planets individually. Do I need to create an object and call these classes, or do I call the objects of planets, and star with the calculation?

```
package universe;
    import java.util.*;

     abstract class CelestialObject {
      private String name;   
      private double size;   
      private long distance;
      public CelestialObject()             { this.name = "";   this.size = 0.0; this.distance = 0; } 
      public CelestialObject(String name)  { this.name = name; this.size = 0.0; this.distance = 0; } 
      public CelestialObject(double size)  { this.name = "";   this.size = size;this.distance = 0; } 
      public CelestialObject(int distance) { this.name = "";   this.size = 0.0; this.distance = distance; } 
      public CelestialObject(String name,  double size, int distance) { this.name = name; this.size = size; this.distance = distance; } 
      public void   setName(String name)      { this.name = name; }         
      public void   setSize(double size)      { this.size = size; }         
      public void   setDistance(long distance){ this.distance = distance; } 
      public String getName()                 { return this.name; }         
      public double getSize()                 { return this.size; }         
      public long   getDistance()             { return this.distance; }     
      abstract public double  calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject otherObj);
    }

    class Star extends CelestialObject { 
    public double calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject otherStar) {
    return this.getDistance() - otherStar.getDistance();
    }

    }

    class Moon extends CelestialObject { 
    public double calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject otherMoon) {
    return this.getDistance() - otherMoon.getDistance();
    }

    }

    class Planet extends CelestialObject {             
      private ArrayList <Moon> moon = new ArrayList <Moon>() ;                            

      public Planet() {}                                         
      public Planet(Moon moon)          { this.moon.add(moon); } 
      public Planet(ArrayList <Moon> moon)
                                        { this.moon = moon;    } 
      public void setMoon(Moon moon)    { this.moon.add(moon); } 
      public void setMoon(ArrayList <Moon> moon)
                                        { this.moon = moon;    } 
      public ArrayList <Moon> getMoon() { return this.moon;    } 
      public Moon getMoon(int position) { return this.moon.get(position); }  
      public double  calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject otherPlanet) {
          return this.getDistance() - otherPlanet.getDistance();}
    }

    class SolarSystem {

      private Star star;
      private ArrayList <Planet> planet = new ArrayList <Planet>() ; 

      public SolarSystem()                 {}                    
      public SolarSystem(Star star)        { this.star = star; Planet planet; } 
      public SolarSystem(Star star, Planet planet)
                                           { this.star = star; this.planet.add(planet); } 
      public SolarSystem(Star star, ArrayList <Planet> planet)
                                           { this.star = star; this.planet = planet;    } 
      public void setStar(Star star)       { this.star = star; } 
      public Star getStar()                { return this.star; } 

      public void setPlanet(Planet planet)    { this.planet.add(planet); } 
      public void setPlanet(ArrayList <Planet> planet)
                                        { this.planet = planet;    } 
      public ArrayList <Planet> getPlanet() { return this.planet;    } 
      public Planet getPlanet(int position) { return this.planet.get(position); }  
    } 

    class Galaxy {
    SolarSystem solarSystem;
    public Galaxy()                 {}                    
      public Galaxy(SolarSystem solarSystem)        { this.solarSystem = solarSystem; } 

      public void setSolarSystem(SolarSystem solarSystem)       { this.solarSystem = solarSystem; } 
      public SolarSystem getSolarSystem()                { return this.solarSystem; } 
    }

    public class Universe {
      Galaxy galaxy;

      public Universe()                 {}                   
      public Universe(Galaxy galaxy)        { this.galaxy = galaxy; } 

      public void setGalaxy(Galaxy galaxy)       { this.galaxy = galaxy; } 
      public Galaxy getGalaxy()                { return this.galaxy; } 




        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Star calc = new Star();

            Moon calc2 = new Moon();

            Galaxy MilkyWay = new Galaxy();

            SolarSystem InterStellerSpace = new SolarSystem();
            MilkyWay.setSolarSystem(InterStellerSpace);

            Star Sun = new Star();
            Sun.setName("SOL");
            Sun.setSize(864938);
            InterStellerSpace.setStar(Sun);

            Planet Earth = new Planet();
            Earth.setName("Blue Planet");
            Earth.setSize(3959);
            Earth.setDistance(92960000);
            InterStellerSpace.setPlanet(Earth);

            Moon BlueMoon = new Moon();
            BlueMoon.setName("Blue Moon");
            BlueMoon.setSize(1097.6);
            BlueMoon.setDistance(238900);
            Earth.setMoon(BlueMoon);

            Planet Mars = new Planet();
            Mars.setName("Red Planet");
            Mars.setSize(2106);
            Mars.setDistance(141600000);
            InterStellerSpace.setPlanet(Mars);

            Moon Phobos = new Moon();
            Phobos.setName("Phobos");
            Phobos.setSize(6.9);
            Phobos.setDistance(5738);
            Mars.setMoon(Phobos);

            Moon Deimus = new Moon();
            Deimus.setName("Deimus");
            Deimus.setSize(3.9);
            Deimus.setDistance(14576);
            Mars.setMoon(Deimus);      

            System.out.println("The Solor System contains the following");
            System.out.println("-- Sun Information --");
            System.out.println("   Name    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getStar().getName());
            System.out.println("   Size    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getStar().getSize());
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet().size(); i ++){
                System.out.println("  ++ Planet Information ++");
                System.out.println("     Name    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getName());
                System.out.println("     Size    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getSize());
                System.out.println("     Distance: " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getDistance());
                System.out.println(" ");

             for (int m = 0; m < MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getMoon().size(); m ++){
                System.out.println("    !! Moon Information !!");
                System.out.println("       Name    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getMoon(m).getName());
                System.out.println("       Size    : " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getMoon(m).getSize());
                System.out.println("       Distance: " + MilkyWay.getSolarSystem().getPlanet(i).getMoon(m).getDistance());
                  System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }  

            System.out.println("Distance between" 
         //**MODIFICATION NEEDED**   
         // Calculate the distance between the two planets
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you make the `calculateDistance` method abstract if the implementations are all the same? Move its implementation back into class, make the class an interface. Then, you can call through your object hierarchy to get from `galaxy`->...->`(planet or moon or any other celestial body).calculateDistance(any other celestial body);`

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid, but what do you mean move it back into class. Do i break it off into its own class extending celestial object?

Comment: Move the body of the method (because in every override its the same) into the the original CelestialBody Class. Make the class and method non abstract; make the class an interface.

Comment: so...you writed all this but you don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The CelestialObject class should be like

```
public abstract class CelestialObject {

    double distance;

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public double calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject cObj) {
        distance = this.getDistance() - cObj.getDistance();
        return distance;
    }

}
```

Make Star Moon Planet extend that Class

Remove the class properties from CelestialObject & put in respective classes. If you want you can override the `calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject` method in respective classes.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how do you make a class an interface? And would.                         abstract public double  calculateDistanceBetweenCelestialObject(CelestialObject otherObj);                                                                             stay with the new interface class?